# How to write middleware for grpc (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I'm attaching a metadata to each client grpc service call (containing a token), and **I'd like to validate this token one the server**, once globally (instead of repeating the validation code in each server service definition).

From my understanding, there is something called "**Interceptor**" for **grpc**, which is somewhat similar to http middleware.

Any example for **Nodejs grpc** interceptor? (or any other way to achieve something similar with http middleware?)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node-grpc doesn't support "middleware" feature yet, as per [answer here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8394#issuecomment-254670533).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [condor framework](http://condorjs.com/). It aims to be something like express for grpc: it's a framwework that adds the middleware functionality on top of the grpc module.

It's relatively new, but it's open source (MIT license), and we're using it on a large project with very good results.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

Auth() just came out(?) with a node package called Mali that serves as a minimalistic grpc framework! Very, very, nascent - so take it with a grain of salt. But very worth looking into :)